# How to turn off keyboard lights on MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

All of sudden my keyboard on my MacBook Pro 2015 has started glowing. I don't know which key I turned on. Is there way to turn it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>F5</kbd> decreases keyboard brightness, <kbd>F6</kbd> increases it.

For more information see the Apple KB article [Adjust the brightness of your backlit keyboard](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202310). If you don't like that the illumination automatically adapts, you can turn it off in System Preferences → Keyboard → Adjust keyboard brightness in low light.